# How print Object {COUNT(*): 4} in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I `console.log()` the property of this object: `{COUNT(*): 4}` ?

`console.log(data.COUNT(*))` doesn't work.

Comment: What object? How did you get that object?

Comment: what you want to print?? `console.log("Object {COUNT(*): 4}");` this is working fine for me.

Comment: I'd argue though that you use a different property name, if possible.

Comment: @FelixKling We meet again! Muahaha!